# Custom ListView with a Checkbox and a Spinner

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, android-spinner

I need to make a `ListView` with this specific attributes:

1) Every row has a `CheckBox` on the left and a `Spinner` on the right;

2) The `Spinner` is active and selectable of and only if the correlated `CheckBox` is checked.

I've managed to achieve (1) using a `SimpleAdapter` and a `ViewBinder`.

I'm also able to put a `onClickListener` to every `CheckBox` using the `ViewBinder`, like this:

```
myCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if (myCheckBox.isChecked()) //call the "enable spinner" function;
    }
});
```

The problem is that I don't know how to find the right `Spinner` from the "enable spinner" function. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Get the row number of your `CheckBox` from the `ListView`.That will solve your problem

Comment: How can i do that? And from where?